# UIGestureRecognizer crashes on < OS3.2

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, gestures, ios-3.x

This is to be expected but I can't seem to find a runtime that works properly as it seems it was a private API before!!!!

At the moment I have and OS3.1.3 responds to the addGestureRecognizer selector!!!!

```
if ( [self.view respondsToSelector:@selector(addGestureRecognizer:)] ) {

        UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
        recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(morePress)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [recognizer release];


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for the system version explicitly:

```
NSString *currentSystemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if([currentSystemVersion compare:@"3.2"] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    //add gesture recognizer
} else {
    // :(
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UIGestureRecognizer is not supported prior to iOS 3.2. Even if the method `addGestureRecognizer:` exists, that doesn't mean it's safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a private api and not supported in versions prior to 3.2.

Apple's doc says:

> To determine at runtime whether you can use gesture recognizers in
>   your application, test whether the class exists and, if it does,
>   allocate an instance and see check if it responds to the selector
>   locationInView:. This method was not added to the class until iOS 3.2.

Sample code:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)];

if (![gestureRecognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(locationInView:)]) {
    [gestureRecognizer release];
    gestureRecognizer = nil;
}
// do something else if gestureRecognizer is nil
```

Explenation:

> To determine whether a class is available at runtime in a given iOS
>   release, you typically check whether the class is nil. Unfortunately,
>   this test is not cleanly accurate for UIGestureRecognizer. Although
>   this class was publicly available starting with iOS 3.2, it was in
>   development a short period prior to that. Although the class exists in
>   an earlier release, use of it and other gesture-recognizer classes are
>   not supported in that earlier release. You should not attempt to use
>   instances of those classes.

Check out the full text [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW40).